# jQuery - append 1 to all IDs in a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This includes nested things. Is this possible? So say I have a jQuery object which looks like

```
<div id="a">
    <section id="b">
         <nav id="c">
         </nav>
    </section>
</div>
```

How do I make it actually represent

```
<div id="a1">
    <section id="b1">
         <nav id="c1">
         </nav>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method in jQuery with callback function to do that

```js
$('div[id],section[id],nav[id]').attr('id', function() {
  return this.id + '1'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <section id="b">
    <nav id="c">
    </nav>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop through all subordinate objects with an id attribute starting from any point in the DOM:

```
$("#a").find("[id]").addBack().each(function() {
    this.id += "1";
});
```

1. This starts with the root object of `id="a"`.
2. Finds all subordinates with an id attribute
3. Adds back the root object
4. Then, adds a "1" to the end of each id in that set

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$('*').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('id',function(idx){
      return idx = idx + 1;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[jQuery("*")](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)** selector to select all dom elements.
But if you want to get all elements inside the body only you can go like this :

```
$("body").find("*").each(function(){
   $(this).attr("id",function(idx){
      return idx = idx + 1;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id]').attr('id',function() {
    return this.id + '1';
});
```

```js
var newID =
$('[id]').attr('id',function() {
  return this.id + '1';
});

$('pre.out').text( $('<div/>').html(newID).html() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
    <section id="b">
         <nav id="c">
         </nav>
    </section>
</div>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```

**RESULT**:

```
<div id="a1">
    <section id="b1">
         <nav id="c1">
         </nav>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clone it like this

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="a">
    <section id="b">
         <nav id="c">
         </nav>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="add" type="button" value="Clone">



 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add").click(function(){
            var newItem = $("#a").clone();
             var newId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

            $(newItem).attr("id","a"+ newId);
            var newSection = $(newItem).children()[0];
            $(newSection).attr("id","b"+ newId );
            var newNav = $(newSection).children()[0];
            $(newNav).attr("id","c"+ newId );

            $("#content").append(newItem);
        });
      });
    </script>
```